# XQuery: expected "return" found "if(" error

Tags: xml, xquery

XML file is a list of `<n>` tags each contains a single number, sorted in ascending order by number inside `<n>` tags. Need to find if three of them satisfies x^2 + y^2 = z^2

Here is my code:

```
declare function local:square($k as xs:decimal?)
as xs:decimal? {
   let $sq := ($k * $k) 
   return $sq
};

declare function local:square_sum($a as xs:decimal?,$b as xs:decimal?)
as xs:decimal? {
   let $sqsum := (local:square($a) + local:square($b)) 
   return $sqsum
};

<result>{
let $doc := doc("emp.xml")/list
let $x := 0
let $y := 0

for $z in //n
    let $zconv := xs:decimal($z/text())
    let $lhs := local:square( $zconv )
    let $rhs := local:square_sum($x, $y)
    if ($lhs = $rhs) then (
    return <t>
                <n>{$x}</n>
                <n>{$y}</n>
                <n>{$zconv}</n>
           </t>
    )

}</result>
```

why is it not running, instead prompting me with an error saying:

> expected "return", found "if("

Please, help sort this out, also check if casting to decimal is okay? for $zconv

---

Based on suggestion Changed code to this:

```
for $z in //n
let $zconv := xs:decimal($z/text())
let $lhs := local:square( $zconv )
let $rhs := local:square_sum($x, $y)
return if ($lhs = $rhs) 
then (   <t>
            <n>{$x}</n>
            <n>{$y}</n>
            <n>{$zconv}</n>
        </t>
)
else (
    $x := $y
    $y := $zconv
)
```

now it says:

> expected ")", found ":="

Need to update $x and $y then rerun the loop for next n-value because Need to satisfy the the given condition.

Comment: XQuery's language semantics don't give you the kinds of guarantees your recent edit depends on (ie. promising that items being iterated over are processed by their order in the input document). If it *did*, that would greatly curtail the engine's ability to optimize by parallelizing loop operations.

Comment: re "Need to update $x and $y": You can't update variables in XQuery. (So yes, the name "variable" is misleading.) To put it another way, a form like `$x := $y` is only allowed when you're *declaring* variable $x (e.g., in a `let` clause). You'll have to think of a different way to solve the problem, one that doesn't involve updating variables.

Comment: (btw, one way to solve this class of problem that doesn't depend on updating variables is with a reducer).

Answer (score 2):

`if` is not a valid element of a [FLWOR](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-flwor-expressions).

One option is to use a `where`:

```
where ($lhs = $rhs)
return <t>...</t>
```

Another is just to move the `if` into the `return`:

```
return if ($lhs = $rhs) then <t>...</t> else ()
```

Comment: changed code, and introduced updating variables $x and $y statements in query, now it shows a different error, as updated the question above, please rectify, please

Comment: If you have a new and different question, that's... well... a *different question*. Ask it separately.